# Why is my memory increasing dramatically in Python

Tags: python

I don't know why my memory keeps dramatically increasing in this code. If I replace
"Value = random.choice(Training_Data)" with "Value = random.choice(Data_Matrix)" this issue goes away but I am interested why "Value = random.choice(Training_Data)" is causing a memory error. I see this memory error looking at task manager and if I iterate in a large enough range will exceed the amount of ram memory I have. I know what the problem is but I unfortunately don't know why the problem is happening.

```
import numpy as np
import random

Data_File = open("Data\even_mnist.csv", 'r')
Training_Data = np.loadtxt(Data_File)
num_rows = np.shape(Training_Data)[0]
Training_Data = np.array(Training_Data)
Testing_Data = []

##print(len((Data_Matrix)))

Data_Matrix = Training_Data

for i in range(500): 
    Value = random.choice(Training_Data)
    Testing_Data.append(Value)

    count = 0
    for lines in Training_Data:
        count = count + 1
        if np.array_equal(lines, Value):
            Training_Data = np.delete(Training_Data, count, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

import sys
`enter code here`print(sys.getsizeof(1))

## 28

`enter code here`print(sys.getsizeof(2**30))

## 32

`enter code here`print(sys.getsizeof(2**60))

## 36

`enter code here`print(sys.getsizeof("a"))

## 50

`enter code here`print(sys.getsizeof("aa"))

## 51

`enter code here`print(sys.getsizeof("aaa"))

## 52

enter link description hereprint(sys.getsizeof([]))

## 56

`enter code here`print(sys.getsizeof(1))

## 64

`enter code here`print(sys.getsizeof([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))

## 96, yet empty list is 56 and each value inside is 28.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).